# How to set an array size at runtime without constucting objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

How do I create an array of GLTexture nullptrs with a size calculated at runtime? . The implementation below creates an array GLTexture pointers initialised with nullptr with a constant size of [11][32]. I want the 11 and 32 shown in the header file below to be interchanged with a value calculated at runtime.

Header File

```
#pragma once
    #include <GLEW\glew.h>
    #include "GLTexture.h"

        namespace Nova
        {
            class TextureBinder
            {
            private:
                GLuint      m_activeUnit;
                GLint       m_maxTextureUnits;
                GLint       m_maxTextureTargets;
                GLTexture*  m_boundTextures[11][32] = {nullptr};

            public:

                static TextureBinder& GetInstance()
                {
                    static TextureBinder binder;
                    return binder;
                }

                TextureBinder(TextureBinder const&) = delete;
                void operator=(TextureBinder&) = delete;


            private:
                TextureBinder();
            };
        }
```

CPP File

```
#pragma once
#include "TextureBinder.h"

namespace Nova
{
    /* zero is the default opengl active texture unit
    - glActiveTexture(unit) only needs to be called for multitexturing
*/
            TextureBinder::TextureBinder()
        :
        m_activeUnit(0),
        m_maxTextureTargets(11)
    {
        glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &m_maxTextureUnits);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Which variable is the array size you want? Your code is lengthy.

Comment: @ArifBurhan sorry missed that! m_boundTextures[m_maxTextureTargets][m_maxTextureUnits]

Comment: are the `m_boundTextures` pointers pointing to textures that this class owns, or are they managed elsewhere?

Comment: @M.M this class does not own them they are managed elsewhere. so they should not be constructed just assigned

Comment: you don't say how you want to address the underlying texture array. Is it ok to refactor it into 2 vector-like objects, or do you need all texture pointers to be addressed as a block?

Comment: @RichardHodges want to address it as 2d array because each row contains a different texture type i.e [0][0 -> m_maxTexureUnits] all are the same type. they will be stored a different row dependent on their type

Comment: What I mean is, do you intend to address them with any gl... function that requires the rows to be in contiguous memory?

Comment: @RichardHodges no.. I do not

Comment: I think you meant to address that to Richard Hodges

Comment: in that case the vector<vector> solution. don't forget the custom destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simplest alternative to code is to use:

```
std::vector< std::vector<GLTexture*> > m_boundTextures;
```

and add to the ctor-initializer list

```
// Numbers can be replaced by variables,
// or you can set the size later using 'resize' member function
m_boundTextures(11, std::vector<GLTexture*>(32));
```

Another option to consider is using a single vector of size `11 * 32` (or whatever your dimensions are) and then using multiplication to access the right index; you could make a helper function for this, e.g.:

```
GLTexture* & lookup(size_t row, size_t col) { return m_boundTextures.at(col + row * row_length); }
```

Comment: if I call the resize member function for the m_boundTextures like so m_boundTextures.resize(11); how would I change the size of std::vector<GLTexture*> that is within it?

Comment: for a single one, `m_boundTextures[n].resize(32);`. For all at once, `for (auto& x : m_boundTextures) x.resize(32);`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you actually want a dynamically sized array (i.e. can be calculated at runtime and works with different sizes), you need to use a loop in your constructor:

```
GLTexture*  **m_boundTextures;

TextureBinder() {
    /* ... */
    m_boundTextures = new GLTexture* *[HEIGHT];
    for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
        m_boundTextures[i] = new GLTexture* [WIDTH];
        for(int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
            m_boundTextures[i][j] = nullptr;
        }
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

And of course make sure to clean up the memory using delete[] (in the same format) in your destructor.

Comment: Or maybe use `std::vector` with which you can set a default value when you resize it ;)

Comment: I prefer the other answer but +1 because I learnt something new !